# cron doesn't execute scripts after setting it up

Tags: cron, job-control

According to [this site](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) I set up cron to execute a script for me, first just trying to get it to work with cat before doing the actual work I need to do (actual work will need root priviliges so I did everything as root to make my life easier later):

```
me> sudo su
root> crontab -e
```

Edited the file as follows, leaving a blank line at the end:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
#which cat outputs /bin/cat
PATH="/bin"

# execute this every minute, if it works, change cat to my script
1 * * * * cat /home/me/source.txt 1> /home/me/destination.txt
```

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193788/restarting-cron-after-changing-crontab-file), restarted the cron service to be sure it loads changes after saving the file and exiting the editor:

```
root> service cron restart
```

And then waited for a few minutes. Nothing happened. Then restarted the computer. Again, nothing. Where did I do it wrong?

Comment: Did you wait till the 1st minute of the hour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your crontab is running at 1st minute of every hour. To run every minute you have to configure like this.

```
* * * * * cat /home/me/source.txt 1> /home/me/destination.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think that through very well. My actual task won't need to run _every_ minute, every 15 minute is enough. Is there a shorthand for that, or do I have to copy the same command 4 times with `0 * * * *`, `15 * * * *`, etc.?

Comment: */15 * * * * cat /home/me/source.txt 1> /home/me/destination.txt.

Comment: 2,17,32,47 also works. I try not to kick a lot of things off in synchronisation. I suspect 2-59/15 is equivalent also.